# Father of lies problem

Tags: probability, bayes-theorem

**Question:** A father claims about snowfall last night. First daughter tells that the probability of snowfall on a particular night is 1/8. Second daughter tells that 5 out of 6 times the father is lying! What is the probability that there actually was a snowfall?

Let $S$ be an event that it snows and $C$ an event that a claim of a snowfall is made

From the answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3394902/tricky-probability-puzzle). The statement "Second daughter tells that 5 out of 6 times the father is lying" supposed to imply that $P(C|S) = \frac{1}{6}$ and $P(C\mid\lnot S) = \frac{5}{6}$ why is that the case?

My interpretation would be that $\frac{5}{6}$ times the claim is made, there was no snowfall i.e $P(S|C) = \frac{1}{6}$

Comment: I don't understand how this is not a duplicate of the question to which you have linked, i.e. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3394902/tricky-probability-puzzle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Second daughter tells that 5 out of 6 times the father is lying"
> supposed to imply that $P(C|S) = \frac{1}{6}$  and $P(C|S^c) =
> > \frac{5}{6}$  why is that the case?

To be fair, the question has quite a bit of ambiguity. The statement

> 5 out of 6 times the father is lying

seems to be a claim about the father's general habits and not specific to the scenario. If we assume snowfall takes a similar probability (the father's lying habits with respect snowfall are the same as his general lying habit), then we can say $P(C|S^c) = \frac{5}{6}$. Why? Because there is a probability of $\frac{5}{6}$ he claims something when it is not true. In a similar manner, if we assume it is snowing, $S$, then there is a probability of $\frac{5}{6}$ he claims it won't snow, $C^c$. Thus $P(C^c | S) = \frac{5}{6}$, and it follows that $P(C | S) = 1 - \frac{5}{6} = \frac{1}{6}$

Comment: You answered the wrong question, which is what is the chance ***that it snowed***, not ***that the father claimed it snowed***.

Comment: I did not answer the wrong question. The poster wasn't concerned with the answer, but was concerned with an intermittent step.

Answer (score 0):

Let $S$ denotes it snows, and $C$ denotes the father claims it snows, and $S^c$ it does not snow, and $C^c$ the father claims it didn't snow.

Bayes rule states:

$$P(S|C) = \frac{P(C|S)P(S)}{P(C)} = \frac{P(C|S)P(S)}{P(C|S)P(S) + P(C|S^c)P(S^c)}$$

$$ = \frac{(1/6) (1/8)}{(1/6)(1/8) + (5/6)(7/8)} = \frac{1}{37}.$$

Comment: Your $P(C)$ calculation is off. The $P(C|S^c)P(S^c)$ = $\frac{5}{6} \frac{7}{8}$